# LibgGDX drawing two separate Textures in FrameBuffer

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

So I am trying to combine multiple `TextureRegion`s in to one by using a `FrameBuffer`. This works extremely well when the `TextureRegion`s originate from the same `Texture` object/file but as soon as I try to combine `TextureRegion`s with different textures of origin, only the `TextureRegion`s from one texture file are drawn. The `TextureRegion`s with different textures of origin do not get drawn.

For example I have two textures:

```
Texture tex1 = new Texture(path to texture 1);
Texture tex2 = new Texture(path to texture 2);

TextureRegion reg1a = new TextureRegion(region from tex1);
TextureRegion reg2a = new TextureRegion(region from tex2);

TextureRegion reg1b = new TextureRegion(another region from tex1);
```

I set up my `FrameBuffer` like this:

```
buffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
```

In my draw method I do the following:

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y);
batch.draw(reg2a, x, y);
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

Using the above draw method, ONLY `reg2` is drawn. reg1 does not show up at all.

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y); 
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

Using this draw method `reg1` IS drawn, so there is nothing wrong with the textures.

```
buffer.begin();
batch.draw(reg1a, x, y);
batch.draw(reg1b, x, y);
buffer.end();

batch.draw(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

This draw method renders BOTH `reg1a` and `reg1b` because they both come from the same `Texture` object/file.

What I want to be able to do is draw to `TextureRegion`s from different `Texture` objects in the same `FrameBuffer` and have them both show up.

I have tried having everything from one Texture in one FrameBuffer, and the other in another FrameBuffer, then drawing those two FrameBuffers into a new FrameBuffer, but that produces the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use separate begin()/end() pairs for each texture draw? I'm pretty sure libgdx does it automatically, but it worth trying.